Sending files to FastAPI from React Native
I was trying to catch the files at my API from Android Emulator, but was struggling for several hours to pass it.
I have a songs add component. Now it contains base-64 translation of files. Swagger is saying i should pass string($binary) however when it was passed thru the docs interface it contain this headers:
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="audio_file"; filename="outrotec.mp3"
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
and then some evil byte code

I tried to Blob, conversion to UIntArray8 even tryed to modify API to recieve a base-64,  but wasn't able to find a solution :( Maybe you can suggest something? ChatGPT was helping me and it seems i should pass the whole file to api, but never find out how.
AddSong.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  Switch,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
import { Input, Button } from '@rneui/themed';
import { Text } from '@rneui/themed';
import { Card } from '@rneui/themed';
import { pick } from 'react-native-document-picker';
import * as RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
import { SongAdd } from '../../api';
import { toByteArray } from 'base64-js';

function AddSong(): React.JSX.Element {

  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  const [genre, setGenre] = useState("");
  const [isPublic, setIsPublic] = useState(false);

  const [audio, setAudio] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [picture, setPicture] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const [loadingAudio, setLoadingAudio] = useState(false);
  const [loadingPicture, setLoadingPicture] = useState(false);

  const postSong = async (song: SongAdd, audioData: string | null, pictureData: string | null) => {
    try {
      setLoadingAudio(true);
      setLoadingPicture(true);

      // Create FormData
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('name', song.name);
      formData.append('description', song.description);
      formData.append('genre', song.genre);
      formData.append('is_public', song.is_public.toString());
      formData.append('audio_file', audioData);
      formData.append('image_file', pictureData);

      const response = await fetch(`http://10.0.2.2:8000/song/base64/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to post song');
      }

      const result = await response.json();
      console.log(result);
      setLoadingAudio(false);
      setLoadingPicture(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      setLoadingAudio(false);
      setLoadingPicture(false);
    }
  };

  const handleSongPost = () => {
    const song: SongAdd = {
      name: name,
      description: description,
      genre: genre,
      is_public: isPublic,
      background: '',
    };

    postSong(song, audio, picture);
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <Card>
        <Card.Title h3={true}>Add Song</Card.Title>
        <Card.Divider />
        <Input value={name} onChangeText={setName} placeholder="Name" />
        <Input value={description} onChangeText={setDescription} placeholder="Description" />
        <Input value={genre} onChangeText={setGenre} placeholder="Genre" />
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Switch value={isPublic} onValueChange={() => setIsPublic(!isPublic)} />
          <Text>Public</Text>
        </View>
        <Text>{audio ? true : false}</Text>
        <Button
          title="Select Audio"
          onPress={async () => {
            try {
              setLoadingAudio(true);
              const result = await pick({
                mode: 'open',
              });
              const fileUri = result[0]?.uri;
              if (fileUri) {
                const fileData = await RNFS.readFile(fileUri, 'base64');
                setAudio(fileData);
              }
              setLoadingAudio(false);
            } catch (err) {
              console.error(err);
              setLoadingAudio(false);
            }
          }}
        />
        {loadingAudio && <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#0000ff" />}
        <Text>{picture ? true : false}</Text>
        <Button
          title="Select Picture"
          onPress={async () => {
            try {
              setLoadingPicture(true);
              const result = await pick({
                mode: 'open',
              });
              const fileUri = result[0]?.uri;
              if (fileUri) {
                const fileData = await RNFS.readFile(fileUri, 'base64');
                setPicture(fileData);
              }
              setLoadingPicture(false);
            } catch (err) {
              console.error(err);
              setLoadingPicture(false);
            }
          }}
        />
        {loadingPicture && <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#0000ff" />}
        <Card.Divider></Card.Divider>
        <Button onPress={handleSongPost} title="Publish" />
      </Card>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default AddSong;

My API endpoint looks like this now:

async def _encrypt_string(string):
    string = string + str(random())
    hashed_string = hashlib.shake_256(string.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest(32)
    return hashed_string



async def _create_file_path(file_name, directory):
    hashed_file_name = await _encrypt_string(file_name)
    return directory + '/' + hashed_file_name + "." + file_name.split(".")[1]


current_user = fastapi_users.current_user()

router = APIRouter(
    prefix='/file',
    tags=['File']
)

image_types = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']


@router.post("/upload/image")
async def upload_image(file: UploadFile = File(...), user: UserTable = Depends(current_user)):
    if file.filename.split(".")[1] not in image_types:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=415, detail="This image is Unsupported Media Type")
    try:

        with open(file.filename, 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, f)

        new_name = file.filename.split('.')[0] + ".jpg"
        file_path = await _create_file_path(new_name, IMAGE_PATH)
        Image.open(file.filename).convert("RGB").save(file_path)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return {"responce": "error",
                "message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
    finally:
        file.file.close()
        os.remove(file.filename)

    return {"responce": "ok",
            "message": f"{file_path.split("/")[-1]}"}


audio_types = ['wav', 'mp3', 'aac', 'aiff']

@router.post("/upload/audio")
async def upload_audio(file: UploadFile = File(...), user: UserTable = Depends(current_user)):
    if file.filename.split('.')[1] not in audio_types:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=415, detail="This audio is Unsupported Media Type")
    try:
        hashed_file_name = await _encrypt_string(file.filename)
        with open(hashed_file_name, 'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, f)

        new_name = hashed_file_name + ".mp3"
        file_path = await _create_file_path(new_name, MUSIC_PATH)
        ffmpeg.input(hashed_file_name).output(new_name).run()
        shutil.copyfile(new_name, file_path)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return {"responce": "error",
                "message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
    finally:
        file.file.close()
        os.remove(hashed_file_name)
        os.remove(new_name)

    return {"responce": "ok",
            "message": f"{file_path.split("/")[-1]}"}

@router.post("")
async def add_song(
        song: Annotated[SSongAdd, Depends()],
        audio_file: UploadFile = File(...),
        image_file: UploadFile = File(...),
        user: UserTable = Depends(current_user)
):
    print(audio_file)
    print(image_file)
    try:
        audio_responce = await upload_audio(audio_file)
        image_responce = await upload_image(image_file)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e

    song_id = await SongRepository.add_one(song, user_id=user.id, audio_file=audio_responce['message'],
                                           cover_file=image_responce['message'])

    return {'response': True, 'song_id': song_id}

Do you have any ideas how i can fix it?
